# rails: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PATCH] "/article/viewing-article-2"):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently learning rails and facing a totally weird issue. 
I am trying to update an existing article by following a tutorial that I am doing, however it is not getting updated. I am receiving the following errors from the terminal and browser respectively:

```
- Terminal: 
* Started PATCH "/article/viewing-article-2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-28 18:54:46 +0200
* No route matches [PATCH] "/article/viewing-article-2"
- Browser: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PATCH] "/article/viewing-article-2"):
```

My routes are such as

```
**routes.erb**

Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root to: 'pages#index'

  post 'article/create-new-article', to: 'pages#create'

  get 'article/viewing-article-:id', to: 'pages#show', as: 'article'

  get 'article/:id/edit', to: 'pages#edit', as: 'article_edit'

  patch 'article/:id/update', to: 'pages#update', as: 'update_article'

  get 'article/new-article', to: 'pages#new'

  get 'article/destroy', to: 'pages#destroy'

end
```

and my controller:

```
controller.erb

def index
    @articles = @@all_articles.all
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    article_params = params.require(:article).permit(:title, :author, :publisher, :content)
    @article.update(article_params)
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

and my html:

```
edit.html.erb

<% content_for :title do %>Editing <%= @article.title %><% end %>

<% content_for :bodycontent do %>

 <h3>Editing <%= @article.title %></h3> 

  <%= form_for @article do |f| %>
     <%= f.text_field :title,  class: 'form-control'%>
     <%= f.text_field :author,  class: 'form-control'%>
     <%= f.text_field :publisher,  class: 'form-control'%>
     <%= f.text_area :content,  class: 'form-control'%> 
     <%= f.submit class: 'form-control btn btn-primary' %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

I am not surely what I am doing wrong, as the selected article does not get updated.

I have loved rails so far, and hope to get better at it. Will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify `form_for` as follows with custom url

```
<%= form_for @article, url: @article.new_record? ? article_create_new_article_path : update_article(@post)do |f| %>
```

but I will suggest you to use Resourceful Routing instead.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for replying Is there any specific reason that you stick with resources? What if you would like rather to use customer url name as it can be done in django and laravel, beautify your URL basically. How can you correctly achieve it in rails

Comment: I don't know about laravel and django, would you like to display some text instead of id?

Comment: let say something like 'article/viewing-article-id

Comment: please check https://github.com/norman/friendly_id gem may work for you.

Answer (score 1):

At first, you really should using [resource routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) for you article model:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'pages#index'
  resources :articles
end
```

This is what controller should look like. About permit params read [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters).

```
def index
  @articles = Article.all
end

def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end

def edit
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  return unless request.patch?
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])

  if @article.update(article_params)
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render :edit
  end
end

private

def article_params
  params.require(:article).permit(:title, :author, :publisher, :content)
end
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for replying Is there any specific reason that you stick with resources? What if you would like rather to use customer url name as it can be done in django and laravel, beautify your URL basically. How can you correctly achieve it in rails

Comment: @Marie Because this is a RESTful :) And there are many reasons why that's good. Just try "RESTful why" in google.

Comment: @Marie Moreover, you can using another unique parameter, like `resources :articles, param: :path_name`